# Strange Glitch with Youtube on S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, video, youtube

i have a strange glitch on an S4 phone
the screen goes "crazy" when the video tries to play

```
Device : S4 I9500
version : 4.4.2 NC1 
Youtube : 10.02.3
```

see the following video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcZG82aUcZc

any ideas to what the problem is?

Comment: The video is private so can't be viewed. Also, you'd be better off providing details of the issue you're having (and refer to the video if it makes it clearer).

Comment: @bmdixon changed to public, it's a video playing issue, easy to see then describe

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my S3 and I got told to uninstall YT, reboot and install it again.

Try that maybe?